# Search or find files that contain string or pattern matching

Tags: regex, perl, pattern-matching

Without using any Perl modules is it possible to do the following in Perl with only a couple of lines of code?

```
find . -type f | xargs grep -l "2000.*Created" | cut -c3-100
```

The above gives me just the filenames of files containing "2000.*Created". I would like to do this in Perl and push results into an array (an array of filenames).

I found that the Perl File::Finder module has a similar ability but in my current work environment, I cannot access or download any modules.

Can this be done in one or two lines of code?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `cut` command at the end? Strip away `"./"` in the path? Also, File::Finder is just a wrapper to File::Find, which is a core module in perl 5.

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible.

```
perl -MFile::Find -lwe '
    find(sub { -f && push @ARGV, $File::Find::name }, '.'); 
    while(<>) { if (/2000.*Created/) { print substr($ARGV,2); close ARGV; } }'
```

[`File::Find`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aFind) is a core module, so it should already be on your system. The `find` subroutine will find all regular files and push them onto `@ARGV`, so that we can read them with the diamond operator. Then we loop through the files checking the content with your regex. If found, we print the file name without the first 2 characters (which I assume is the equivalent of `cut -c3-100`). The `close ARGV` line is a short circuit to prevent multiple matches.

Answer (score 0):

I like File::Find better for this example -- it is much more portable and File::Find can do some really nifty stuff. However, I'll mention an approach which can be useful for other commands without built in support.

```
open F,'find . -type f | xargs grep -l "2000.*Created" | cut -c3-100 |' || die 'cannot execute';
while(<F>) { chomp ; push(@a,$_)}
```

Note the trailing pipe (`|`) on the open ... this is important because Perl will automagically do all the work of hooking up pipes for you.

This can also be written using the newer 3 argument open:

```
open my $fh, '-|', 'find . -type f | xargs grep -l "2000.*Created" | cut -c3-100' || die 'cannot execute';
while(<$fh>) { chomp ; push(@a,$_)}
```

As a side note, `find | xargs` is going to have some problems if you have filenames with spaces. You can work around that with the `-print0` action on `find` and the `-0` flag on `xargs`:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -l "2000.*Created" | cut -c3-100
```